# Visual Studio 2013 Indentation Not Working While Writing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, resharper, indentation

I have such a code:

```
class Myclass
{
}
```

I now want to add some code, e.g. a method. I go right after the } and press enter expecting to get this (| is the place of the cursor):

```
class Myclass
{
    |
}
```

However I get this:

```
class Myclass
{
|
}
```

If I now enter a method it stays like this:

```
class Myclass
{
public void A()
    { }
}
```

My configuration for indentation is correct because once I press Ctrl+K, D it gets fixed. Also I checked Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting -> Indentation and "Indent block contents" is checked.

This is happening on Visual Studio 2013 with Resharper 8.1. I suspended Resharper temporarily and there is no difference. On the same machine I have Visual Studio 2012 with Resharper and it works normally.

Does anyone know what configuration has to be changed to have the indentation work during writing?

Answer (score 16):

I found the setting that is messing this up: it is Options->Text Editor->All Languages->Tabs->Indenting. I had it set to Block and it should be Smart

Answer (score 1):

I added this to .editorconfig (resharper config file)

`brace_style = next_line`

if anyone wants to go through the configurations in editorconfig file
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2017.1/EditorConfig_CSHARP_BracesPageSchema.html

Answer (score 1):

For VS 2019 remove ".editorconfig" file. Located in project/src/