# Indentation after braces in C# with ReSharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, resharper

does anyone know how i can get an indentation after pressing enter on a open brace?

Instead of:

```
public void SomeFunction()
{
[cursor here]
}
```

this here:

```
public void SomeFunction()
{
    [cursor here]
}
```

So after typing the open { i don't want to have the same indention as the brackets but be indented by one tab

Comment: I get indentation by default. Maybe there is something wrong with your settings?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Also with the lates ReSharper 10? Without Resharper it works correctly, but I wanna have it working even with ReSharper

Comment: I have Resharper 9.2.

Comment: @YacoubMassad happens to me also with that

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this earlier today. I found out that it's not ReSharper, but Visual Studio. Solution here: [Visual Studio 2013 Indentation Not Working While Writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23267754/visual-studio-2013-indentation-not-working-while-writing)